# How can I split an array before starting new iteration in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have no idea how to this split array. Actually, my target position for splitting is 99999999

This is my coding:

```
ssq=[]
for i in range (12):
    for j in range (len(decision1[i])):
        w=uu[i][decision1[i][j]]
        ssq.append(w)   
    j=j+1
    ssq.append(99999999)  
i=i+1
ssq=np.array(ssq)
```

My current output is

```
array([       0,        0,     1500,     1500,     1500,     1500,
           1500,     1500,        0, 99999999,        0,        0,
              0,        0,        0,        0,        0, 99999999,
              0,        0,        0, 99999999,      500,      500,
            500,     1000,     1000,     1000,      500,
           2000, 99999999,     1000,     1000, 99999999,...])
```

But my target is

```
array([  0,        0,     1500,     1500,     1500,     1500,
         1500,     1500,        0 **]**,[        0,        0,
         0,        0,        0,        0,        0 **]**,
         [0,        0,        0 **]**,[      500,      500,
         500,     1000,     1000,     1000,      500,
         2000**]**, [1000,     1000**]**,...])
```

Comment: is it possible you could just `.reshape(-1,12)` your array?

Comment: What's with all the asterisks in the target array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to increment the loop variable.  The `for` will do that.

```
ssq=[]
for i in range (12):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(decision1[i])):
        w=uu[i][decision1[i][j]]
        row.append(w)   
    ssq.append(row)  
ssq=np.array(ssq)
```

Even better is:

```
ssq=[]
for i in range (12):
    ssq.append( [uu[i][j] for j in decision1[i]] )
ssq=np.array(ssq)
```

Or even:

```
ssq = [[uu[i][j] for j in decision1[i]] for i in range(12)]
ssq = np.array(ssq)
```